# OBIEE 12c: Dashboard Prompting to change analysis view

Tags: dashboard, prompt, obiee

Hope you could help me with the following question:
I have an analysis, which is run with 2 different data aggregation: by region or by ownership.
Currently I built 2 separate analysis to show both views.
But is there any way I can customize a prompt to let users choose which view they want to see? The dropdown will look like "Region view"/"Ownership" view & depending on the choice report view would show columns with regions or with owners.
Thank you!

Answer (score 0, accepted):

What you're looking for is an out-of-the box view type in the analysis which is called a "View Selector" and which shows the logical name of the views of the analysis you let people select.

It's not a dashboard prompt. While it's possible to do it in a dashboard prompt that means a lot of weird config instead of just using the tool as it's built and designed.